# xCode publish source code that I bought from someone else

Tags: ios, xcode

I bought a source code for xCode online, therefore I think there is some certificate thing that were assign by the original developer.

I want to know where do I have to change to my own certificate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project certificate is changed on the **Build Settings** tab of your project.

Use the search box in the Build Settings tab to find **"Code Signing"**.